# Running PHPUnit within a Docker container with PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, phpstorm

I want to configure my PhpStorm IDE to run PHPUnit tests within my Docker container.

It seems like I'm restricted to either using a local PHP executable, or one through SSH, as the interpreter for the tests.

I could install an SSH service on my PHP container, but it seems like a bit of a hacky solution, and articles online discourage installing an SSH service on containers.

To try and get a local interpreter working, I tried creating a bash script  that would proxy calls to PHP within the container, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Run PHP through Docker
docker exec -t mycontainer_php_1 php "$@"
```

This works perfectly when I run it myself, but when I point PhpStorm to it as a local PHP interpreter, it doesn't recognize it as a valid PHP executable.

So what's a good way to get this working?

Comment: *"... it doesn't recognize it as a valid PHP executable."* That's because IDE expects certain (standard) output from interpreter to verify its version and settings. In this particular regard I may recommend: 1) first create PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm using real php (or pass all parameters to php as is); 2) once it was added to PhpStorm, alter your script to use your docker. P.S. Newly release v10 has some support for Docker -- have you seen it? Can it do what you need?

Comment: Since I'm proxying to php within Docker, in theory it should also be able to determine the version by calling the script I gave and `--version`. Are you saying I should try and trick PHPStorm by pointing it to a real local php interpreter so it recognizes it, then swap it out for the bash script? I have PHPStorm 10 installed, but it appears that the only Docker features it has is deployment related.

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. But if you think a bit more further .. it quite likely will not work (I mean the latter -- running PHPUnit tests) as IDE uses helper script for integration purposes (which it will need to deploy there somehow, unless it's done automatically) + paths most likely will differ with local ones...

Comment: That's going to be the next problem. For now I just want to be able to get PHPStorm to recognize a PHP executable that runs in Docker.

Comment: I would go with SSH approach. There is nothing "hacky", it is how it works with vagrant boxes. It is much more robust, tested by JetBrains and users. I see no harm installing sshd in a container on **dev** machine.

Comment: Alex: would you please demonstrate how best to install sshd on a debian image as an answer?

Answer (score 17):

With PhpStorm now having [better integration with Docker engine](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/11/docker-remote-interpreters/) (including Docker for Mac), you can now just do the following (or [read this article](https://blog.alejandrocelaya.com/2017/02/01/run-phpunit-tests-inside-docker-container-from-phpstorm/)):

**Command line:**

1. **Pull the `phpunit` Docker image:** `docker pull phpunit/phpunit`
2. *(Mac and maybe Windows)* **Bridge the Docker socket to the `API_URL`:** `socat -d TCP-LISTEN:2376,range=127.0.0.1/32,reuseaddr,fork UNIX:/var/run/docker.sock`

**Then Phpstorm:**

1. **Configure connection to Docker engine:**

   - Go to *Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Docker*
   - Create a new Docker configuration with `API URL` set to:

     - Linux: `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`
     - Windows and Mac: `http://127.0.0.1:2376` or `tcp://localhost:2376`
2. **Configure the remote interpreter:**

   - Go to **Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP**
   - Create a new PHP CLI interpreter by:

     - Clicking on `...` then `+` and 'Remote...'
     - Select **Docker** with:

       - ServerImage:
       - Image name: `phpunit/phpunit:latest`
       - PHP executable: `php`
3. **Configure Phpunit:**

   - Go to **Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit**
   - Create new Phpunit configuration (`+` then 'By Remote interpreter...' and select
   - Set `Use Composer Autoloader`
   - Path to script: `/opt/project/vendor/autoload.php`
   - Default configuration file: `/opt/project/phpunit.xml.dist`
4. **Try to run your tests!**

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))
docker run --rm --sig-proxy=true -v ${DIR}:${DIR} -w ${DIR} --pid=host php:cli php "$@"
```

just put it in some file, chmod +x it => just tested with idea and is recognized just fine :)

The trick to get all of phpstorms helper scripts to work really is to mount the directory the php executable resides in.
In case this script is not in the folder of your phpunit executable and source code you will have to extend it to also mount those.

(important side note here: they must be mounted to the same folder in container and host obv :) )

Edit after a few months now, but maybe helpful to some:
Worked this out with a WordPress example here:
http://original-brownbear.github.io/2015/12/23/phpunit-docker-phpstorm.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a concern. You are saying that I should run php in a new, separate container. I'm worried that this PHP won't have the same settings turned on as in the php-fpm container I already have running and in which I have been running phpunit manually so far.

Comment: Fair point :) I mean you have multiple options here,
the easiest might be to simply substitute php:cli with the image your php-fpm container runs in my opinion.
How about that  ?

Comment: Even if it's the same image, it won't use all the mounts and such that I already have configured in my docker-compose.yml. I'm mostly worried about that. If there would be a reliable way to replicate that, that might be sufficient to warrant me allowing using a separate container for running tests.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little here?

Is this just about volumes or also about links(networking)?
If it is the former the adjustment to the above script would be trivial.
For networking the solution becomes more involved and I'd like to only amend the above with the solution for it if necessary :)

Comment: It's that too, but it's more about that I have e.g. an environments file referenced for my current php-fpm, and I want to use the same env vars. I also have a custom php.ini. There are several things like that and I want to make sure that exactly the same things are used.

Comment: Uff thinking this through there seems to be no general solution in existance,
If you want paste your docker-compose.yml and I could create the run command that has all the mounting and stuff in it here real quick.
Solving this 100% generally is impossible imo.
This would essentially be asking for the php executable to live in both the host and container env at the same time to statisfy PHPStorm and still communicate with the other containers.
SSH though is likely less hacky than any solution I could come up with. Only upside would be the performance of a custom docker run command I think.

Comment: If you are using docker composer, you may use `docker-compose run <your container name> php` command instead of plain docker. It will create a new container with the configuration from your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: I can't seem to be getting PHPStorm to recognize my php bash script is a valid executable. Would you please elaborate on what needs to be achieved with the PHPStorm helpers? I don't quite understand how they work. I cannot paste any code here, because unfortunately the code is proprietary. By the way I don't really care about PHPUnit yet; first of all I just want to make sure that at least I can get PHPStorm to recognize that bash file as a valid PHP interpreter.

Comment: It turns out that PHPStorm doesn't recognize the executable because I'm passing an environment file with `--env-file=` to `docker run`. What I don't understand, however, is why this is causing the issue, and what I could do to mitigate it.

Comment: Oh it turned out that I was relying on `pwd` there to help point to the env file, however the working directory is not what I was expecting -.- I should have stuck to just using `DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))` like you said. By the way, out of all this, only this bit is necessary to make phpstorm treat the script as a php executable: `docker run -v /tmp/:/tmp/ php:cli php "$@"` (you forgot to mention the necessary /tmp/ bit)